# OpenSSL Get Subject Alternative Name from certificate

Tags: ios, objective-c, openssl, x509certificate

I'm developing an iOS app that will need to read Subject Alternative Name from an certificate (.pfx).

Security.framework doesn't have a way to get this information, so you I'm using OpenSSL(openssl-1.0.1e)

To read Subject Name I'm using X509_get_subject_name(certificate) and for Issuer I'm using  X509_get_issuer_name(certificate) and is working.

The problem is the Subject Alternative Name. I can't find any function to return this information.

Is it possible using OpenSSL to get the Subject Alternative Name? How?

**Edit:**

I imported the certificate into MAC keychain. 
On Subject Alternative Name I see NT Principal Name and RFC 822 Name.

I tried this but it is returning NULL:

```
GENERAL_NAME *name = (GENERAL_NAME*)X509_get_ext_d2i(cert,NID_subject_alt_name, NULL, NULL)
```

I'm reading certificate with this:

```
X509 *cert;
CFDataRef der = SecCertificateCopyData(certificate);
const unsigned char * ptr = CFDataGetBytePtr(der);
int len = CFDataGetLength(der);
d2i_X509(&cert,&ptr,len);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the x509 subject alternative name by using X509_get_ext_by_NID() then X509_get_ext() :

```
int loc = X509_get_ext_by_NID(X509 *, NID_subject_alt_name, -1);

if (loc >= 0) {
  X509_EXTENSION * ext = X509_get_ext(X509 *, loc);
```

then you have to parse the extension using sk_GENERAL_NAME_num() and sk_GENERAL_NAME_value(), or X509_get_ext_d2i().

Comment: I'm trying this: (GENERAL_NAME*)X509_get_ext_d2i(cert,NID_subject_alt_name, NULL, NULL);
But I'm is null. Should it work?

Comment: In theory you should only get NULL if cert is NULL, the certificate has no subject alternative name extension or more than one. Could you post the code loading the certificate into cert and the content of the certificate (or the output of openssl x509 -in <certificate> -text if you prefer so)?

Comment: I'm using X509_get_subject_name() and is working. I imported the certificate into mac keychain. On Subject Alternative Name I see NT Principal Name and RFC 822 Name(They have the same value). Could that be the problem?

Comment: I don't think so, but without seeing the content of the certificate I am just guessing.

Comment: I'm trying this command: openssl pkcs12 -info -in CERT.pfx. And none of the extensions are being displayed. Only the subject and issuer are.
The certificate that I'm using is .pfx. Is it OK to use a certificate .pfx?

Comment: Yes, I think it's perfectly fine.